# Magento 2 override Model that implement interface

Tags: magento2

I have want to override `Amazon\Payment\Model\OrderInformationManagement` Class model `saveOrderInformation` function and want not add one extra argument to this function.

So anyone have idea override `Amazon\Payment\Model\OrderInformationManagement` Model.

Custommodule/Amazon/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Amazon\Payment\Model\OrderInformationManagement" type="Custommodule\Amazon\Model\OrderInformationManagement" />
</config>
```

Custommodule/Amazon/model/OrderInformationManagement.php

```
<?php
namespace Custommodule\Amazon\Model;
use Amazon\Core\Client\ClientFactoryInterface;
use Amazon\Core\Exception\AmazonServiceUnavailableException;
use Amazon\Core\Helper\Data as CoreHelper;
use Amazon\Payment\Api\Data\QuoteLinkInterfaceFactory;
use Amazon\Payment\Api\OrderInformationManagementInterface;
use Amazon\Payment\Domain\AmazonSetOrderDetailsResponse;
use Amazon\Payment\Domain\AmazonSetOrderDetailsResponseFactory;
use Exception;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use AmazonPay\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class OrderInformationManagement implements OrderInformationManagementInterface
{
    private $session;
    private $clientFactory;
    private $coreHelper;
    private $amazonSetOrderDetailsResponseFactory;
    private $quoteLinkFactory;
    private $logger;
    private $productMetadata;
    private $quoteFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Session $session,
        ClientFactoryInterface $clientFactory,
        CoreHelper $coreHelper,
        AmazonSetOrderDetailsResponseFactory $amazonSetOrderDetailsResponseFactory,
        QuoteLinkInterfaceFactory $quoteLinkFactory,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        ProductMetadata $productMetadata
    ) {
        $this->session                              = $session;
        $this->quoteFactory                         = $quoteFactory;
        $this->clientFactory                        = $clientFactory;
        $this->coreHelper                           = $coreHelper;
        $this->amazonSetOrderDetailsResponseFactory = $amazonSetOrderDetailsResponseFactory;
        $this->quoteLinkFactory                     = $quoteLinkFactory;
        $this->logger                               = $logger;
        $this->productMetadata                      = $productMetadata;
    }

    public function saveOrderInformation($amazonOrderReferenceId, $allowedConstraints = [], $orderId = 0)
    {
        try {

            $quote   = $this->session->getQuote();
            $storeId = $quote->getStoreId();

            $this->validateCurrency($quote->getQuoteCurrencyCode());
            $this->setReservedOrderId($quote);

            $storeName = $this->coreHelper->getStoreName(ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId);
            if (!$storeName) {
                $storeName = $quote->getStore()->getName();
            }

            $data = [
                'amazon_order_reference_id' => $amazonOrderReferenceId,
                'amount'                    => $quote->getGrandTotal(),
                'currency_code'             => $quote->getQuoteCurrencyCode(),
                'seller_order_id'           => $orderId ? $orderId : $quote->getReservedOrderId(),
                'store_name'                => $storeName,
                'custom_information'        =>
                    'Magento Version : ' . $this->productMetadata->getVersion() . ' ' .
                    'Plugin Version : ' . $this->coreHelper->getVersion()
                ,
                'platform_id'               => 'AUGT0HMCLQVX1'
            ];

            $responseParser = $this->clientFactory->create($storeId)->setOrderReferenceDetails($data);
            $response       = $this->amazonSetOrderDetailsResponseFactory->create([
                'response' => $responseParser
            ]);

            $this->validateConstraints($response, $allowedConstraints);
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            throw $e;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error($e);
            throw new AmazonServiceUnavailableException();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: what you mean by "and want not add one extra argument to this function" ? @Niranjan

Comment: want not add saveOrderInformation($amazonOrderReferenceId, $allowedConstraints = [], $orderId = 0, $quoteId) want to add $quoteId extra to function.

Comment: when you override core class you don't need to implement interface just need to extend core class 
see my answer

Comment: it working fine now.

Comment: great !! @Niranjan

Comment: Thank you only missing                  parent::__construct($session,$clientFactory,$coreHelper,$amazonSetOrderDetailsResponseFactory,$quoteLinkFactory,$logger,$quoteFactory,$productMetadata);

Answer (score 1):

To override model:

> di.xml

```
          <?xml version="1.0"?>
         <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Amazon\Payment\Model\OrderInformationManagement" type="Vendor\Module\Model\OrderInformationManagement" />
```

and in **Vendor\Module\Model\OrderInformationManagement**

add below method with your custom logic

```
                        <?php
        namespace Custommodule\Amazon\Model;

        use Amazon\Core\Client\ClientFactoryInterface;
        use Amazon\Core\Exception\AmazonServiceUnavailableException;
        use Amazon\Core\Helper\Data as CoreHelper;
        use Amazon\Payment\Api\Data\QuoteLinkInterfaceFactory;
        use Amazon\Payment\Api\OrderInformationManagementInterface;
        use Amazon\Payment\Domain\AmazonSetOrderDetailsResponse;
        use Amazon\Payment\Domain\AmazonSetOrderDetailsResponseFactory;
        use Exception;
        use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
        use Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata;
        use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
        use Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException;
        use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
        use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
        use AmazonPay\ResponseInterface;
        use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

        class OrderInformationManagement implements \Amazon\Payment\Model\OrderInformationManagement
        {
            private $session;
            private $clientFactory;
            private $coreHelper;
            private $amazonSetOrderDetailsResponseFactory;
            private $quoteLinkFactory;
            private $logger;
            private $productMetadata;
            private $quoteFactory;

            public function __construct(
                Session $session,
                ClientFactoryInterface $clientFactory,
                CoreHelper $coreHelper,
                AmazonSetOrderDetailsResponseFactory $amazonSetOrderDetailsResponseFactory,
                QuoteLinkInterfaceFactory $quoteLinkFactory,
                LoggerInterface $logger,
                \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
                ProductMetadata $productMetadata
            ) {

                parent::__construct($session,$clientFactory,$coreHelper,$amazonSetOrderDetailsResponseFactory,$quoteLinkFactory,$logger,$quoteFactory,$productMetadata);
            }

            public function saveOrderInformation($amazonOrderReferenceId, $allowedConstraints = [], $orderId = 0)
            {
                try {

                    $quote   = $this->session->getQuote();
                    $storeId = $quote->getStoreId();

                    $this->validateCurrency($quote->getQuoteCurrencyCode());
                    $this->setReservedOrderId($quote);

                    $storeName = $this->coreHelper->getStoreName(ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId);
                    if (!$storeName) {
                        $storeName = $quote->getStore()->getName();
                    }

                    $data = [
                        'amazon_order_reference_id' => $amazonOrderReferenceId,
                        'amount'                    => $quote->getGrandTotal(),
                        'currency_code'             => $quote->getQuoteCurrencyCode(),
                        'seller_order_id'           => $orderId ? $orderId : $quote->getReservedOrderId(),
                        'store_name'                => $storeName,
                        'custom_information'        =>
                            'Magento Version : ' . $this->productMetadata->getVersion() . ' ' .
                            'Plugin Version : ' . $this->coreHelper->getVersion()
                        ,
                        'platform_id'               => 'AUGT0HMCLQVX1'
                    ];

                    $responseParser = $this->clientFactory->create($storeId)->setOrderReferenceDetails($data);
                    $response       = $this->amazonSetOrderDetailsResponseFactory->create([
                        'response' => $responseParser
                    ]);

                    $this->validateConstraints($response, $allowedConstraints);
                } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                    throw $e;
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $this->logger->error($e);
                    throw new AmazonServiceUnavailableException();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: @NiranjanGondaliya please add your code in question what you have tried before

Comment: just edit question.

Answer (score 0):

create di.xml into Vendor/Module/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Amazon\Payment\Model\OrderInformationManagement" type="Vendor\Module\Model\OrderInformationManagement" />
</config>
```

create OrderInformationManagement.php file into Vendor/Module/Model

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class OrderInformationManagement extends Amazon\Payment\Model\OrderInformationManagement    
{
   public function yourCustomMethod()
   {
      //do what you want
   }
}
```

Run below commands from root

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

you can get reference from [here](https://magenticians.com/override-model-magento-2/)

Comment: Above way i know but above way is for simple model but above not working when model implement interface. I have try but got error.